# Why Ubuntu 18.04 decided to close all my apps and log off?

Tags: 18.04

I am bit confused - I have locked my laptop and when opened (logined) I have found that all my VPN's, terminals and chrome tabs have been closed.

What is the reason for this?

Please instruct me what should I check?
Logs? 
Please advise.

```
steve@steve-ThinkPad-T480:~$ ls -al /var/crash
total 93436
drwxrwsrwt  2 root  whoopsie     4096 Dec 12 16:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root  root         4096 Feb 10  2019 ..
-rw-r-----  1 steve whoopsie 41629796 Dec 12 12:53 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 steve whoopsie  8325264 Dec 12 12:53 _usr_bin_Xwayland.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 steve whoopsie 45704740 Dec 11 15:43 _usr_lib_rstudio_bin_rsession.1000.crash



steve@steve-ThinkPad-T480:~$ ls -al .local/share/gnome-shell/
total 16
drwx------  2 steve steve 4096 Dec 17 16:55 .
drwx------ 28 steve steve 4096 Dec 17 16:42 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 steve steve 1422 Dec 17 16:55 application_state
-rw-rw-r--  1 steve steve  880 Dec 11 15:47 notifications

free -h:

steve@steve-ThinkPad-T480:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        7.0G        2.7G        1.9G        5.7G        6.1G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G

steve@steve-ThinkPad-T480:~$ sudo lshw -C memory
[sudo] password for steve: 
  *-memory                  
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 3
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: RMSA3300ME78HBF-2666
          vendor: Fujitsu
          physical id: 0
          serial: 12B58072
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 8
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 9
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: b
       version: N24ET53W (1.28 )
       date: 10/17/2019
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 15MiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 21
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e824c000-e824ffff
```

Comment: That does not seem like a *logoff*, but a *crash*. Look for a crash file in /var/crash to find out what crashed and why.

Comment: @user535733 I have seen the crash file, what should I look for there?
I can share it here but I would like to get some pointers what should I check?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`

Comment: @heynnema done please have a look

Comment: Have you intentionally selected wayland? At your login screen, select your username, click the cogwheel icon, and select `Ubuntu` or `Ubuntu w/GNOME` or some such. See if the problems go away. You can also show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: status please...

Comment: @heynnema
`steve@steve-ThinkPad-T480:~$ ls -al .local/share/gnome-shell/
total 16
drwx------  2 steve steve 4096 Dec 17 16:55 .
drwx------ 28 steve steve 4096 Dec 17 16:42 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 steve steve 1422 Dec 17 16:55 application_state
-rw-rw-r--  1 steve steve  880 Dec 11 15:47 notifications`

Comment: @SteveS It's best to edit your question and post the screen lines there. In comment it's all jumbled together.

Comment: @SteveS Thanks for the information. Have you tried the non-Wayland login that I suggested earlier? If so, did it help?

Comment: @heynnema did it but I don't like the interface.

Comment: @SteveS What is different between the two that you don't like? Is your problem something that occurred only once, or does it happen every time?

Comment: @heynnema sorry for the late reply, without Wayland my mouse and keyboard doesn't work. It seems freezed.
Regarding Wayland it seems that it's a bit stuck sometimes (on config screen/window and sometimes restarts).

Comment: @SteveS With all of the various problems you have, I think it's important to do a memory test. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: @SteveS Also, lets check your BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and give me that output, and your make/model #/serial # of your computer/motherboard, and I'll look if there's an update.

Comment: @SteveS Lastly, show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: @heynnema please explain what `free -h` does and `sudo lshw -C memory`

Comment: @SteveS both commands show how your memory/swap are being used, and how the memory is configured. Used to help me determine if you've got a memory or swap issue causing your problems. The dmidecode command will tell you what version BIOS you have, so we can determine if it's up to date (I'll also need the make/model #/serial #). Also to try and fix your problems. All three are harmless.

Comment: @SteveS postnote: I know it's a `Lenovo Thinkpad T480`, but their web site wants serial # so that it can narrow down the correct BIOS update required.

Comment: @heynnema thank you so much for your help, I will provide it to you within 10 - 12 hours from now, when I will get to my pc.
I will update the question!

Comment: @SteveS Good. Ping me here with "@heynnema"

Comment: @SteveS I don't use my linkedin account for support here.

Comment: @heynnema done please have a look

Comment: Have you done the dmidecode (I need the answer, and your serial # to check for BIOS updates), and run the memory test (very important with your crashes)? FYI: for maximum memory speed, it's best to use a pair of 8G sticks vs one 16G stick.